# Hudson "Perform Maven Release" fails on committing to svn+ssh on different port

Tags: svn, maven-2, ssh, hudson, release

We have svn+ssh setup on non-standard port.

We added svn+ssh credential in Hudson, when it asked us. Ordinary build goes fine, without any problems:

```
Started by user anonymous
Checking out svn+ssh://xxx:22222/usr/local/svn_repo/repo/project/trunk
A         pom.xml
U        .
At revision 485
```

However, when we try to "Perform Maven Release" (M2 Release Plugin), Hudson fails just before committing release changes:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Unable to commit files
Provider message:
The svn command failed.
Command output:
ssh: xxx:22222: Name or service not known
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Connection closed unexpectedly

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Trace
org.apache.maven.BuildFailureException: Unable to commit files
Provider message:
The svn command failed.
Command output:
ssh: xxx:22222: Name or service not known
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Connection closed unexpectedly

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:715)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:284)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutorInterceptor.execute(LifecycleExecutorInterceptor.java:65)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at hudson.maven.agent.Main.launch(Main.java:165)
    at hudson.maven.MavenBuilder.call(MavenBuilder.java:165)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$Builder.call(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:750)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$Builder.call(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:694)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:114)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:270)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Unable to commit files
Provider message:
The svn command failed.
Command output:
ssh: xxx:22222: Name or service not known
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Connection closed unexpectedly

    at org.apache.maven.plugins.release.PrepareReleaseMojo.execute(PrepareReleaseMojo.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at hudson.maven.agent.PluginManagerInterceptor.executeMojo(PluginManagerInterceptor.java:182)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    ... 28 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Nov 24 14:41:20 CET 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/155M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

I have the same "Name or service not known", when I try listing something from the machine:

```
mah@hudson:~$ svn list svn+ssh://xxx:22222/usr/local/svn_repo/repo/project/trunk
ssh: xxx:22222: Name or service not known
svn: Connection closed unexpectedly
```

In order for this to work, I would need to modify tunnel section in subversion config. But why I cannot perform a release with Hudson?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a standard [SVN Issue (1942)](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1942).

It also states that there is a patch for it. I don't know if the patch could be incorporated into Hudson, but you can open an [Bug/Feature Request](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa).

Standard, and probably easiest, workaround is to [define an host alias](http://svn.haxx.se/users/archive-2004-09/0574.shtml).